# R does not import bottom rows of CSV file

Tags: r, excel, csv

I think my problem may be in excel but am not entirely sure. I've tried everything I can think of as well as suggestions from the web but nothing is working.

I convert the excel file to .CSV. The file has 12 columns and 516 observations (combo of lat/long, text,ids, time, date) plus a header. On my first import, R recognized all 12 columns and only 104 of the 516 rows.

I then went back to the excel file, typed "1" in an empty generic formatted cell, and "special paste --> multiply" to all numeric cells. When sorted, the sort recognized all rows. The filters recognize all rows.

I checked that the print area included all rows. I also set the last cell in work range to the correct cell.

When I converted to CSV then loaded in R, it now recognizes 504 out of 516 rows. The bottom 12 are omitted.

When I copy and paste the bottom 12 rows into a new excel spreadsheet and load them separately, they load. However, if I recopy both the 12 observations and 504 observations into a new sheet, the same 12 are again omitted in R.

Apologies that there is no reproducible example, and that it may actually be an excel problem, but I am really stuck here.

Does anyone know what may be the issue here? I would be very grateful for any help.

***EDIT***

Reading the file in with the command `read.delim(file.choose(), header=TRUE, sep=";")` instead of the command I had been using `read.table(file.choose(), header=TRUE, sep=";")` fixed this problem.

Comment: what is your R code for importing the file? In my experience, `read.delim` is the most robust, and you should also note that you might have comment characters in your sheet which are causing lines to get dropped. I would review the docs for [read.table, etc.](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html). Note the defaults `blank.lines.skip = TRUE` and `comment.char = "#"`, among others which could be causing this.

Comment: you also might want to open your CSV file in a raw text editor, such as Sublime, with whitespace characters visible and verify that the formatting is correct.

Comment: Thank you!!! Switching to read.delim worked like a charm. I had been using read.table and adding sep=";"    Thank you again you've made my night!